# Search list with data retrieved from api in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to create a search list based on data I have retrieved from API.

I have data from API and I need to make it searchable in a list.

```
 console.log('home');
 console.log('date: ', this.todaydate);
 this.userService.isAuthenticated(this);
 let headers = new Headers({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
     'Authorization': this.getAccess.idToken
 });
 this.http.get('************' + this.todaydate, {
         headers: headers
     })
     .map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe(
         data => {
             this.events = data;
         },

         err => console.log("error is " + err),

         () => console.log('read events Complete ' + this.events)
     );
 }

 isLoggedInCallback(message: string, isLoggedIn: boolean) {
     console.log("The user is logged in: " + isLoggedIn);
     if (isLoggedIn) {
         this.eventService.sendLoggedInEvent();
         //this.nav.setRoot(ControlPanelComponent);
         //this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage);
         this.cognitoUtil.getIdToken(new IdTokenCallback(this));
         console.log('token from dashboard here: ', this.getAccess.idToken);
     } else {
         this.eventService.sendLoggedInEvent();
         //this.nav.setRoot(ControlPanelComponent);
         this.nav.setRoot(LoginComponent);
     }
 }

 presentModal() {
     let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(SearchPage);
     modal.present();
 }

 getItems(event) {
 }
 }
 export class IdTokenCallback implements Callback {
     constructor(public home: SearchPage) {
     }

     callback() {
     }

     callbackWithParam(result) {
         this.home.getAccess.idToken = result;
     }
 }
```

[image: above is the html image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: getItems(ev : any ){

            this.initializeItems();

       let val = ev.target.value;
        if (val && val.trim() !=''){

           this.items = this.items.filter((item)=>{
                return 
       (item.eventname.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase())  > -1);


         })
       }
       }




above is my get items code for ts.

Comment: the  eventname is the return json data for the list that i need to search. But it says the 'eventname' does not exist on the type string